# Stop CSS3 columns breaking paragraphs up

Tags: html, css, layout, multiple-columns

How would I go about stop the browser from breaking up paragraphs when using CSS3 columns? I have this code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box"><!-- text --></div>
    <div class="box"><!-- text --></div>
    <div class="box"><!-- text --></div>
    <div class="box"><!-- text --></div>
    <div class="box"><!-- text --></div>
    <div class="box"><!-- text --></div>
    <div class="box"><!-- text --></div>
    <div class="box"><!-- text --></div>
</div>

.container {
    column-count: 3;
 }
```

This is a visual representation of what I want. On the left, is what happens by default, and on the right, what I want to happen.

[image: css3 columns]

I don't mind if the columns are unequal lengths, what's important is that none of the divs are broken across columns.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The setting `break-inside: avoid` would do this, according to the description of [`break-inside`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#break-before-break-after-break-inside) in the CSS Multi-column Layout Module. But [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn) is limited so that you need to use additionally some other settings that reflect ideas in older drafts, implemented in some browsers:

```css
.container {
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
 }
div.box { 
  text-indent: 1em; /* To show paragraph starts. */
  page-break-inside: avoid; /* For Firefox. */
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid; /* For Chrome & friends. */
  break-inside: avoid; /* For standard browsers like IE. :-) */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">This is a short paragraph.</div>
    <div class="box">This is a short paragraph, too.</div>
    <div class="box">This is yet another short paragraph.</div>
    <div class="box">This is a short paragraph.</div>
    <div class="box">This, too, is a short paragraph.</div>
    <div class="box">This is a longer paragraph, which may get divided into two columns..</div>
    <div class="box">This is a short paragraph.</div>
    <div class="box">This is a short paragraph.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I came here now because I have a case where this doesn't seem to work on Chrome -- neither Mac nor Win (FF OK on Win, Ubuntu and Mac, and FF on Ubuntu); however the above in addition to inline-block on .box (as per the next answer) did the trick. Hm.

Comment: What should we try if none of these solutions actually work?

Answer (score 11):

[image]On the .box add the style:

```
.box {
    display:inline-block;
    ... other styles ...
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/murog/1/

Comment: `display: inline-block;` works, thanks for the answer :) however, the other answer I got, which involves using `break-inside: avoid;` works better for what I'm using it for. But as a fall back, `display: inline-block;` works fine :)

Comment: Note: if you have multiple consecutive paragraphs that are shorter than half you column width - they will render on the same line.  Highly unlikely to happen with real content, but it was confusing me when I was testing my styles. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29402718/924597 for workaround.

Comment: Unfortunately none of these answers work. I have same issue, several paragraphs in one div. Need the <p> content to not break, and stay together, I've tried everything, nothing works to keep the text together, nothing works to push the <p> to the next column. You may be able to wrap all <p> elements in one div and tell the div not to break, but that is not ideal.